# cant remove quotes using replace in the data factory pipeline expressions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

so I have a lookup which outputs
`{ "firstRow": { "result": "[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]" }`
I want to set the output to a variable in a array form so I can use the output in a for each loop.

I want  `[[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]]`

problem is when I use `@createArray(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.result)`
I get value `["[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]"]` this is treating the two list as one when i run it through for each loop.

I have tried to use replace function to remove " but it is not working.
i.e `@createArray(replace(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.result,'"[','['))` 
This should ahve removed " and given me
`[[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]"]`

but its not, i am still getting the quote. anyone knows why is it not working

i have also tried`@createArray(replace(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.result,'\"[','['))`
and still getting output like `["[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want  `[[\"0A09\",\"0B01\",\"0B02\",\"0B04\"],[\"0F78\",\"0F79\",\"0F80\"]]`

You can use `json()` function to generate the required array from the string.

This is my lookup output as same as yours:

[image]

Use the below expression to convert the above string into a two dimensional array.

```
@json(concat('[',activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.result,']'))
```

Here, for sample I have used it in an array variable. You can directly give this expression in the ForEach activity.

[image]

**Output array:**

[image]